Book about a girl who went to a grocery store that had monsters
There was this book I read in middle school. It was about this girl that lived in a society. She went to a grocery store that had monsters in it. I think there might have been a sequel where she was in a group that went out and hunted these monsters. I can’t remember anything else. Does anyone know what I’m talking about? I was in middle school around 2012-2016 if that helps. Does this book sound like Legend by Marie Lu?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What kind of society?  A secret society, a fantasy-type mediaeval society, or just a modern city?  What kind of monsters?  Why were they in the store?  Were they shopping?

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

It doesn't sound in the slightest like Legends by Marie Lu.

Monster by A. Lee Martinez? If this isn't it maybe you could highlight some of the plot points that made your story different from this.

@John Rennie: I concur, "Monster" is a likely candidate ...

Might be Clean Sweep (2013), the first book in the Innkeeper Chronicles by Ilona Andrews - The main protagonist is attacked by a monster at the supermarket.
Here's the blurb:

On the outside, Dina Demille is the epitome of normal. She runs a quaint Victorian Bed and Breakfast in a small Texas town, owns a Shih Tzu named Beast, and is a perfect neighbor, whose biggest problem should be what to serve her guests for breakfast. But Dina is...different: Her broom is a deadly weapon; her Inn is magic and thinks for itself. Meant to be a lodging for otherworldly visitors, the only permanent guest is a retired Galactic aristocrat who can’t leave the grounds because she’s responsible for the deaths of millions and someone might shoot her on sight. Under the circumstances, "normal" is a bit of a stretch for Dina.
And now, something with wicked claws and deepwater teeth has begun to hunt at night....Feeling responsible for her neighbors, Dina decides to get involved. Before long, she has to juggle dealing with the annoyingly attractive, ex-military, new neighbor, Sean Evans—an alpha-strain werewolf—and the equally arresting cosmic vampire soldier, Arland, while trying to keep her inn and its guests safe. But the enemy she’s facing is unlike anything she’s ever encountered. It’s smart, vicious, and lethal, and putting herself between this creature and her neighbors might just cost her everything.*

